# Customer profiling and Anomaly detection -Python

Tags: python, pandas, classification, profiling, profile

Thank you for taking the time to check this question.
I am interested in creating a profile for customers buying pattern.
Once I created a profile for everyone, we take unseen data and check with the profile to see if the customers followed their profile if not raise a flag. In this manner we do not create a set alert for all buyers but we can detect anomaly based on individual buyers to benchmark against their profile.

Any thoughts or inputs to how to approach this problem.
If you have a course or tutorial on this matter please feel free to suggest it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried already?  sounds like machine learning (scikit-learn).  Plenty of books and tutorials out there.  Google is your friend.

Comment: I have used group by do segment customers based on their buying pattern and location currency. If the new data doesn't follow any of the individual profile created. I raised an alert. I did this across the whole data set of customers and their transaction. 
This raises alerts but not as meaningful as it can.

In order to use Sci-kit learn we do not have an anomaly already detected because we dont know what an anomaly is for each individual customer.

Answer (score 1):

You can either go by supervised learning method, basically machine learning. Also, buying pattern, I would suggest to explore more about RFM rule i.e. recency, frequency and monetary value. This will help you in creating features for model or profile customers.

Comment: Thank you Nitin, 
I will try the RFM model.
Can you please elaborate on the Supervise Learning part. Is there any model you think that can fit the bill.
Thank you